# Is it possible to disable specific React warnings from Jest (using Create React App)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

Recently, React started giving depreciation warnings for `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method. I am using a library that utilized this function and the maintainers haven't updated their codebase yet.

Currently, any time I run my tests, whether it is in development or in CI, I keep getting ~30 lines of depreciation warnings for each component that the maintainer provides.

Is there a way to suppress these warnings (at least in development)?

EDIT:

I am willing to add certain comments in my files to disable warnings from a specific package if there is a chance:

```
// some line to disable warnings for this package
import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-dates';
```

Comment: You can try to override `console.warn`

Comment: This will remove warnings everywhere. I do not think this is a good idea. When overriding it in my test files, nothing happens.

Comment: Did you try with the [--silent](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#silent) parameter for Jest?

Comment: mark those methods UNSAFE_ . i.e. ur componentWillReceiveProps will become UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps . try this. i think this will get you rid of those warnings.

Comment: @HarshitAgarwal this is not my library; so, I can't do it.

Comment: @Daniele but this disables all warnings. I need to disable only this warning. Or only warnings for a specific package.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to disable all warnings that meet some condition, keeping all other warnings, for all tests:

```
const originalWarn = console.warn.bind(console.warn)
beforeAll(() => {
  console.warn = (msg) => 
    !msg.toString().includes('componentWillReceiveProps') && originalWarn(msg)
})
afterAll(() => {
  console.warn = originalWarn
})
```

---

[React codebase](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/66a474227b18c76eb2f7c24108227e8628502f8c/packages/react/src/__tests__/createReactClassIntegration-test.js#L555) also contains `expect(render(...)).toWarnDev(...)`, but that's not included in [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect), you might need to investigate more if you want to use that feature.

Comment: where do i put the code provided? because if i copy/past the code exactly in my class file it has errors.

Comment: @LukeCarelsen in the file that contains tests, see [Setup and Teardown](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown) Jest documentation

Comment: You could do a shorter: `console.warn = jest.fn();`. This should be put outside of the `describe` test-suits.

Answer (score 6):

Similar in concept to a previous answer, but a bit easier would be:

```
jest.spyOn(global.console, 'warn').mockImplementationOnce((message) => {
  if (!message.includes('componentWillReceiveProps')) {
    global.console.warn(message);
  }
});
```

If you wanted to do it across tests you could do:

```
let consoleSpy;

beforeAll(() => {
  consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(global.console, 'warn').mockImplementation((message) => {
    // same implementation as above
});

afterAll(() => consoleSpy.mockRestore());
```

Comment: For me this caused infinite resursion when real warnings occurred. Use `const originalWarn = console.warn.bind(console.warn)` and then call originalWarn in implementation per @Aprillion's answer.

Answer (score 4):

A variation on @Aprillion's answer...

I wanted to suppress certain **error** messages in **all** tests (in a `create-react-app` application).

I added this to my `setupTests.js`:

```js
// This error is a bug fixed in React 18: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/22114.
// Suppress it for all tests.
const BOGUS_UNMOUNTED_ERROR = (
  "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component."
);
const originalError = console.error.bind(console.error);
console.error = (...args) => !args.toString().includes(BOGUS_UNMOUNTED_ERROR)
  && originalError(...args);
```

I guess the most important difference is that I replaced `(msg)` with `(...args)` in two places, so that all arguments to `console.error()` were passed through. Without this, I was getting `%s`'s in my console error messages that should have been filled in with other arguments.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a way to fix these warnings for any library using react-codemod.
Since this library does not work inside node_modules so have to do a little hack.

Run:

```
 yarn add -D react-codemod
 open ./node_modules/react-codemod/bin/cli.js
```

- Remove/comment line (72) >

  ```
  + // args.push('--ignore-pattern=/node_modules/');
  ```

Run:

```
./node_modules/.bin/react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles
```

To this question answer with the path of the library, you want to fix...

> “On which files or directory should the codemods be applied?”

```
./node_modules/react-dates/lib/** // or any library with issue
```

This could be a temporary fix till react-codemod support node_modules libraries.
You can also fork the library and remove the line for yourself and use it like this inside your CI pipeline to not get any warnings like this anymore.

Comment: I would strongly advise against modifying anything in node_modules. Doing this would require checking in your node_modules directory, which you also normally shouldn't do. Forking the library is fine, though using jest.spyOn to ignore the message is a much better idea.

Comment: If you really really really need to modify node_modules directly, you should use patch-package https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to swallow all errors in one test, and this works.

```
  /* These lines swallow the StrictMode warnings that are thrown because of react-draggable */
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  const originalError = console.error.bind(console.error);

  beforeAll(() => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.error = () => true;
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.error = originalError;
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just add this line above whatever is showing the warning. I have tried this in VScode so i'm not sure if it works with others. This disables whatever warning that will be displayed in the next line.

// eslint-disable-next-line

Comment: answer is not relevant